# Did Steve Rogers have post high school education?

Tags: marvel, captain-america

Did Cap ever go to college? In any continuity, did Cap or Steve get a formal degree?

Comment: I came here to take some classes and kick some asses. And I ain't seeing no classes.

Comment: possibly - according to the film, we see on his medical chart when he is given 4F status, that he was born on July 4, 1918 - which, if the film is set in 1942, would make him 24 years old. It's also possible that Endgame Rogers, upon his return back to the past, could have attended on the GI Bill

Comment: https://screenrant.com/facts-steve-rogers-before-captain-america/#:~:text=Between%201932%20and%201936%2C%20Steve,the%20George%20Washington%20Educational%20Campus.&text=After%20graduating%20from%20George%20Washington,art%20at%20Auburndale%20Art%20School.

Comment: If you're asking whether Captain America went to college, we can't be sure. However, pre-super soldier serum Steve did attend some high school

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be conflicting info out there regarding whether the Steve Rogers of the Marvel 616 universe attended college or not. In *[Captain America #247](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_America_Vol_1_247)*, he claimed he'd wanted to go to art school, but couldn't afford it.

[image: Captain America v1 247 011]

Whereas his more recent official bios state that he graduated high school and spent a year in art school. Obviously, both sources suggest he didn't complete college or gain a formal degree.

[image: Avengers - Roll Call 008]

It's worth noting that the reliability of Steve's memories was somewhat questionable at the time that *Captain America #247* was published. In *[Captain America #225](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_America_Vol_1_225)*, it was established that he had total amnesia regarding the first 18 years of his life.

[image: Captain America v1 225 005]
[image: Captain America v1 225 006]

In the same issue, he underwent a mind probe to restore his lost memories, and amongst other things, recalled that he'd begun attending Empire State University in September 1941.

[image: Captain America v1 225 014]

However, in *Captain America #247*, these were revealed to be false memories implanted by the US military, with the aim of confusing the enemy in case Steve were ever captured and interrogated.

[image: Captain America v1 247 010]

In that issue, he was given an old journal of his by S.H.I.E.L.D. agent, Tim "Dum Dum" Dugan, and it was this which brought back what were apparently his true memories, including the fact that he couldn't afford art school.

If we wanted to reconcile Steve's official bio with his statement that he couldn't afford art school, we could surmise that he did attend art school for a year, but couldn't afford to continue for whatever reason.

**Either way, there's no indication I know of that any version of Steve Rogers ever gained a formal degree**.

Answer (score 5):

According to Steve's [S.H.I.E.L.D. File](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.H.I.E.L.D._Files) his education is:

> **Education:**
>
> George Washington High School, Brooklyn, NY
> 1932 - 1936
>
> Auburndale Art School, Brooklyn, NY
> 1937-38
>
> [image: Steve Rogers S.H.I.E.L.D. File giving relevant data about the person including a mugshot; the Education section is quoted above]
> <sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

I'm not sure if Auburndale Art School counts as a college but I would think it does and so in the MCU the answer is yes. There appears to be no mention of grades or what degree, if any, he received though.

Comment: That record only indicates that he attended art school for a year though, not that he actually graduated with a degree. The 616 version of Steve also attended art school for a year, according to his official bio, but the wording used implies that he didn't complete the course, since those bios normally specify if a character has actually graduated college, as opposed to merely attending college (or the equivalent) for a given period.

Comment: @LogicDictates Sure, I'm not making any assumptions as to whether he graduated/got a degree or not.